# Ending a while loop when it reaches matching numbers

Tags: java

I need to end this while loop when it reaches a matching number such as 88, 77, and so on.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      int userNum = scan.nextInt();
      if ((userNum >= 20) && (userNum <= 98)){
         System.out.print(userNum + " ");
         while ((userNum != 11) || (userNum != 22) || (userNum != 33) || (userNum != 44) || (userNum != 55) || (userNum != 66) || (userNum != 77) || (userNum != 88) || (userNum != 99)){
         userNum = userNum - 1;
           System.out.print(userNum + " ");  
         }

      }
      else{
         System.out.print("Input must be 20-98");
      }
      System.out.print("\n");
   }
}
```

However, when it runs it never leaves the loop, even when the number reaches one of the matching ones I had in the while loop. please help.

Comment: Just replace the || check with the && check, and it will work

Answer (score 3):

```
if(userNum != 11) || (userNum != 22) || (userNum != 33) || (userNum != 44) || (userNum != 55) || (userNum != 66) || (userNum != 77) || (userNum != 88) || (userNum != 99)
```

Will always be true, because `userNum` cannot be all of those values at once. Substitute `||` for `&&`:

```
if(userNum != 11) && (userNum != 22) && (userNum != 33) && (userNum != 44) && (userNum != 55) && (userNum != 66) && (userNum != 77) && (userNum != 88) && (userNum != 99)
```

This can be made easier using the modulus operator:

```
if(userNum % 11 != 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in this line.
`if(userNum != 11) || (userNum != 22) || (userNum != 33) || (userNum != 44) || (userNum != 55) || (userNum != 66) || (userNum != 77) || (userNum != 88) || (userNum != 99)`

If userNum is any number, it cannot be 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, and 99 at once, which means your program will keep running. As @Carcigenicate stated, you want && (and) operators.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the && operator here instead of OR

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      int userNum = scan.nextInt();
      if ((userNum >= 20) && (userNum <= 98)){
         System.out.print(userNum + " ");
         while (userNum != 11 && userNum != 22&& userNum != 33 && userNum != 44 && userNum != 55 && userNum != 66 && userNum != 77&& userNum != 88 && userNum != 99){
         userNum = userNum - 1;
           System.out.print(userNum + " ");  
         }

      }
      else{
         System.out.print("Input must be 20-98");
      }
      System.out.print("\n");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code appears to be searching for multiples of `11`, so I would prefer testing the remainder of eleven. Also, you can use `x--` instead of `x = x - 1`. Finally, a `do-while` loop would make this a bit cleaner. Like,

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int userNum = scan.nextInt();
if (userNum >= 20 && userNum <= 98) {
    do {
        System.out.print(userNum + " ");
        userNum--;
    } while (userNum % 11 != 0);
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code to ending a while loop when it reaches matching numbers using array.

```
public class stopWhileTest{
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        int[] number = {11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88};
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int userNum = scan.nextInt();
        if ((userNum >= 20) && (userNum <= 98)){
            System.out.print(userNum + " ");
            while(!contains(number,userNum)){
                userNum = userNum - 1;
                System.out.print(userNum + " ");
            }
        }
        else{
            System.out.print("Input must be 20-98");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
        scan.close();
    }

    public static boolean contains(final int[] array, final int v) {
        boolean result = false;
        for(int i : array){
            if(i == v){
                result = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Hope this solution works.